# BlazeDS 3.2.0 and JBoss 5.1 DatabaseServerLoginModule

Tags: apache-flex, flash, jboss, blazeds

Has anyone that is using BlazeDS RemoteObject been able to retrieve the authenticated user roles through JBoss DatabaseLoginModule login policy?

I'm using using BlazeDS 3.2.0 and JBoss 5.1. I can successfully authenticate but I, users with unauthorized roles are still able to login. I've changed the Realm in default/jbossweb.sar/server.xml "strict" as shown below:

```
<Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccAuthorizationRealm" certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping" allRolesMode="strict" />
```

The same login module is being used in other web apps and it works just fine. In default/conf/login-config.xaml I have:

```
<application-policy name="MyPolicy">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code = "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name = "dsJndiName">java:/DefaultDS</module-option>
            <module-option name = "principalsQuery">SELECT PASSWD FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID=?</module-option>
            <module-option name = "rolesQuery">SELECT ROLE_ID, 'Role' FROM ROLES WHERE USER_ID=?</module-option>
            <module-option name= "hashUserPassword">true</module-option>
            <module-option name= "hashAlgorithm">SHA-256</module-option>
            <module-option name= "hashEncoding">base64</module-option>
         </login-module>
     </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

Other details: - WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="false">java:/jaas/MyPolicy</security-domain> 
</jboss-web>
```

WEB-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="flex.messaging.security.TomcatValve" /> 
</Context>
```

WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml

```
<security>
  <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand" server="JBoss">
     <per-client-authentication>false</per-client-authentication> 
  </login-command>
  <security-constraint id="custom-admin-access">
    <auth-method>Custom</auth-method> 
    <roles>
         <role>ADMIN</role> 
    </roles>
   </security-constraint>
</security>
```

WEB-INF/flex/remoting-config.xml

```
<destination id="MyRemoteService">
    <properties>
        <source>test.blazeds.MyRemoteService</source> 
        <scope>session</scope> 
    </properties>
    <security>
        <security-constraint ref="custom-admin-access" /> 
    </security>
</destination>
```

I know I could try to implement my own JDBC based Tomcat Realm but that's something like I would like to avoid since JBoss also provides other login-modules, such as LDAP, that I might come to use in the future.

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and download the BlazeDS source code and after some debugging I realized that it might have just been me and my expectations when it came to the login behavior. Still, I'm a little bit confused about it and maybe someone can clarify me in the actual
process since BlazeDS documentation does not explain it in a clear way.

My configuration is very simple, one amf destination for
RemoteObejct usage and one security-constraint with the allowed roles.
In this scenario I was expecting the ChannelSet.login to fail if the
user does not include the expected roles. Instead, the login succeeds
which, in my current design allows the user to proceed.

After debugging I realized that TomcatLoginCommand.isUserInRole method
is only called after a RemoteObject method is called but never during
the ChangeSet.login command. To confirm it, I associated
security-constraints with some methods of the destination (see below -
as shown in the documentation). As expected, the RemoteObject method
would not be called when logging in with a user that did not have the
given roles but all was good if the role was present.

```
<destination ...>
...
    <include-methods>
      <method name="fooMethod"/>
      <method name="barMethod" security-constraint="custom-admin-access"/>
    </include-methods>
...
</destination>
```

Based on this, my questions still are: Is this the intended behavior? Shouldn't ChangeSet.login fail immediately if the authenticated user does not participate in the
allowed set of roles?